# RedirectMatch on url NOT containing any parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to write a rule where the redirection would occur ONLY if the URL is called without any parameters, so for example this WOULD redirect:

`domain.com/a/b/`

but this WOULD NOT and it would go through just fine, loading this specific URL:

`domain.com/a/b?x`

So how do I write a RedirectMatch in that scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `RedirectMatch` directive.

You should use `mod_rewrite` rules for this as this one:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^a/b/?$ /target [L,R=301]
```

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` condition returns true if query string is empty.

Comment: Hmm, tried that, can't get it to work... it's not redirecting whether there is a query string or not.

Comment: I just added that to existing .htaccess in the folder that already works just fine with other parameters and redirects in place. I entered domain.com/a/b, domain.com/a/b?x, etc, and they all load just fine.

Comment: Move this rule to top of your .htaccess and make sure this is in site root .htaccess